# How to send one ngModel new string but send the already existing another string to db?

Tags: ionic-framework

Hello i want to change the title with ngModel (mediaData) and keep the description string (mediaDetails) or vice versa.

Right now it changes the one BUT doesn't keep the value i dont want it to change.

**.html**

```
<ion-input placeholder="{{mediaDetails.description}}" [(ngModel)]="mediaData.description" [ngClass]="mediaDetails.description"></ion-input>
```

**.ts**

```
export class EditPage {
  mediaDetails: any = {};
  mediaData: any = {};

  this.mediaDetails = this.navParams.get('mediaDetails');
```

Answer (score 0):

this is **two way** binding

```
 [(ngModel)]="mediaData.description"
```

use regular expression for one way binding

```
  {{mediaData.description}}
```

for **ion-input** use like this :

```
  <ion-input placeholder="{{mediaDetails.description}}" value="{{ mediaDetails.description }}" [ngClass]="mediaDetails.description"></ion-input>
```

Comment: Hello AbdulAzeem it doesn't change it. In fact it deletes the other value (description or viceversa) for the record i call the API function like this.  this.userData.editMedia(this.mediaData)

Comment: if you use {{ mediaDetails.description }} as value ?

Comment: Then how will it return mediaData? i need that t send the new parameters. Shouldn't there be an ngModel?

Comment: if you use ng-model changes made in html will reflect in ts file and vice versa

Comment: according to your current code what you will input will go to mediaData.description and vice versa

Answer (score 0):

the answer is

```
    <ion-input placeholder="{{mediaDetails.title}}" value="{{mediaDetails.title}}" [(ngModel)]="mediaData.title" [ngClass]="mediaData.title ? '' : 'required'"></ion-input>
```